# WatchKit: Handoff from static interface of Long Look?

Tags: ios, push-notification, watchkit, apple-watch, handoff

Our app has implemented the handoff functionality between push notification on the Apple Watch (in our `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController` subclass) and the main iPhone app. It works with dynamic interface of the notification long look.

However, when I open a notification from the notification center on the Apple Watch (thus resulting in a static long look), handoff is **not** working with iPhone. The handoff icon is not shown at all on the iPhone lock screen.

I also noticed that handoff does work from static long looks of:

- Apps **without** custom long look implementations (the ones with roundrect icons in notification center)
- Messages app on the Watch, and maybe more from Apple

Anyone noticed this problem too? Are there any workarounds that make handoff work from a static long look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no way to call the call the appropriate Handoff methods for a static notification - owing to the inability to use a custom class - there's no way to accomplish what you're looking for at this time.